# strange behavior when writing c++ codes with decrement operator

Tags: c++

I am a beginner of c++, I meet a strange code when coding,below is the problem.

```
 class INT
{
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const INT &i);

public:
    INT(int i) :m_i(i){};
    INT(const INT& i)
    {
        m_i = i.m_i;
    }
    INT& operator++()
    {
        ++(this->m_i);
        return  *this;
    }
    const INT operator++(int)
    {
        INT temp = *this;
        ++(*this);
        return temp;
    }
    INT& operator--()
    {
        --(this->m_i);
        return  *this;
    }
    const INT& operator--(int)
    {
        INT temp = *this;
        --(*this);
        return temp;
    }
    int& operator*() const
    {
        return (int&)m_i;
    }
private:
    int m_i;
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const INT &i)
{
    os << "[" <<i.m_i<< "]";
    return os;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    INT i(5);
    cout << i++;
    cout << ++i;
    cout << (i--);
    cout << --i;
    cout << *i;
}
```

I get a result

```
[5][7][-858993460][5]5
```

my expected result is

```
[5][7][7][5]5
```

I am using Visual Studio 2013. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
const INT& operator--(int) { ... }
```

is wrong. You are returning a reference to an object in function scope. The reference becomes invalid after the function returns. Change it to:

```
INT operator--(int) { ... }
```

While at it, you don't need the `const` in:

```
const INT operator++(int) { ... }
```

Change it to:

```
INT operator++(int) { ... }
```

Comment: Any idea why it doesn't fail the same way for his `++` operator that returns `INT&`? Just dumb luck since they're both UB?

Comment: @Barmar The `++` operator in the OP's post returns a `const INT`, not a `const INT &`